# Drilling through json data

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

I have this API https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2015-09-07&end_date=2015-09-08&detailed=false&api_key=DEMO_KEY

I'm having trouble drilling down to the data:

How can I get it to give me only the data where is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid": true? Using jQuery Ajax and it is giving me undefined...

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    var url = "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2015-09-07&end_date=2015-09-08&api_key=DEMO_KEY";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data.near_earth_objects.2015-09-08);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    var url = "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2015-09-07&end_date=2015-09-08&api_key=DEMO_KEY";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            // you can't use dot syntax with numbers:
            // console.log (thing.123);
            // try this instead:
            var neos = data.near_earth_objects['2015-09-08'];
            // and to find the hazardous asteroids:
            var hazardous_neos = neos.filter (function (d) {
                // return true to add d to the array returned from filter()
                // return false to NOT add d to the array from filter()

                // if we want hazardous asteroids then
                // since is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid is a
                // boolean where true means it's hazardous then
                // we can simply return its value
                return d.is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid;

                // if we want NON-hazardous asteroids we can do:
                //return d.is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid == false;
            });

            console.log (hazardous_neos);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Then please mark it as "accepted" so that others can easily find the answer if they have a similar problem.

Comment: How would one check / filter for false?

Comment: Return `true` in the lambda passed to `filter()` if you want to add the element to the array returned from filter. Return `false` if you *don't* want the element in the resulting array returned from filter. [See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). I've also modified the answer I gave to help illustrate.